# Calling a method on an injected property (from an ASPX page)

Tags: asp.net, spring

I'm teaching myself Spring.NET and to see if I've got everything wired up properly, I'm trying to call a method on an object that I have tried to inject into an ASPX page (I know this isn't probably best practice)

This is in my aspx file (so I'm trying to call the 'orderDescription' getter on the orderService property of this aspx page)

```
[some html here]
<%= OrderService.orderDescription() %>
[some more html here]
```

In my Web.config, I've got this in my 'spring, objects' section

```
  <object type="Default.aspx">
    <property name="OrderService" ref="orderService"/>
  </object>
```

When I run it, it tells me that I need an object instance before I can call a static method, i.e. it thinks I'm trying to call 'orderDescription' as a static method on OrderService. But Spring is supposed to have injected 'OrderService' as a property of my aspx page, so why can't I call it this way.

I know I'm missing something simple but I can't figure it out. Appreciate any tips

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a summary of what you need to do to get this working](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/web.html).  Originally I was going to say that "Default.aspx" wasn't the name of a class, but I guess spring.net must translate that for you.  Did you put the `SpringPageHandler` configuration in your web.config?  Also, do you actually have a property named `OrderService` defined on the class and of the appropriate type?  I would expect that if you did, then you would actually get a NullReferenceException (another small note, you said `OrderService.orderDescription()` is trying to call the getter on the orderDescription property - but you put parenthesis like it is a method call (if it is just a property it should just be `OrderService.orderDescription` [no parenthesis])).

Comment: Hi, many thanks for the tips. I'll give them a try tonight, you could be right I'm just calling the methods in the wrong way. I think I'm trying to learn too many new things at once :)